in build oidc authentication stuck at /callback
In debug mode code /callback i working and when i build the code and deploy it on iis then it started throwing error
URL stuck @/callback
"http://localhost:4200/callback?code=a0yBTY9dXgT-GojN_Kbg4bV4638zFS39jw0AAAAG&state=06e543f089e34b67b66effb1a5a4ed6c"

we have used react-oidc library to configure this oidc authentication using pkce approach
below is then app.js code for reference
import { AuthProvider } from "oidc-react";

function App() {
  const oidcConfig = {
    onSignIn: async (user:any) => {
      alert('You just signed in, congratz! Check out the console!');
      window.location.href = '/'; // Redirect to home page after sign-in
    },
    authority: 'https://uatapp.exampleserver.com',
    clientId:  'bjose45kgm',
    responseType: 'code',
    redirectUri:'http://localhost:4200/callback',
    scope: 'openid profile',
  };

  return (
    <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>
      <Router />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;


